# Add a table inside a Content Controller using javaScript

Tags: javascript, office365, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add a table inside a content controller in my OFFICE365 task pane app. This is the code I am using.

```js
function createContentControlForTable(tableName, number_columns, number_header, number_body, number_footer) {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var number_cells = number_header + number_body + number_footer;
            var range = context.document.getSelection();
  
            var myContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
            myContentControl.tag = "Table name:" + tableName;
            myContentControl.title = "Table name:" + tableName;
            myContentControl.appearance = "Tags";
            myContentControl.style = "Normal";
            myContentControl.insertText("", 'replace');
            myContentControl.cannotEdit = false;
            myContentControl.insertTable(2, 2, Word.InsertLocation.end);
       
            context.load(myContentControl, 'id');

            return context.sync().then(function () {               
                myContentControl.tag = myContentControl.tag + " id:" + myContentControl.id;
                myContentControl.title = myContentControl.title + " id:" + myContentControl.id;
                showNotification("Table", "Table added successfuly");
                console.log('Created content control with id: ' + myContentControl.id);

                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    console.log('Inserted a table in the content control.');
                });
           
           
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            });
           
        });
```

Here I am using `'contentControlObject.insertTable(rowCount, columnCount, insertLocation, values);'` for my task.

As the `'insertTable'` method is not working with https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js, I used the beta_version (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js) of Office.js for my app.

But the problem is, when execute the line `'return context.sync().then(function (){'`, it gives an error saying,

```
ItemNotFound: ItemNotFound\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:188232)\n   at pi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:210600)\n   at ht (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:210687)\n   at g (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:210507)\n   at l (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:209093)
```

I appereciate if anybody can help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the beta version of the JavaScript API for word and this issue happened due to some issue with the API and now it has been resolved. Now

```
insertTable(rowCount: number, columnCount: number, insertLocation: string, values: string[][])
```

is working properly as expected.

The insertLocation value can be 'Start', 'End', 'Before' or 'After'  and values is Optional (Optional 2D array)